# How can I get rid of the second close button (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using the libraries from jquerymobile.com
There are two close buttons on my page for some reason - I'd like to get rid of the close button that has the text "Close" on it.

```
<div data-role="dialog" data-url="dialog.html" class="ui-dialog ui-page ui-body-a ui-page-active" role="dialog">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="d" data-position="inline" class="ui-corner-top ui-overlay-shadow ui-bar-d ui-header" role="banner">
        <a href="#" data-icon="delete" data-rel="back" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-d" title="Close" data-theme="d"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
            <span class="ui-btn-text">Close</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow"></span></span>
        </a>
        <h1 class="ui-title" tabindex="0" role="heading" aria-level="1">What is a dialog box?</h1>
    </div>    
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="c" class="ui-content ui-body-c ui-corner-bottom ui-overlay-shadow" role="main">
        <p> What is a dialog box you may ask? </p>
        <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show more of your page, I dont see the additional close button on http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/9UveF/

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" /><script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="foo">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="banner">
   <h2>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li><a href="#dialog.html" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slidedown">What is Mobile?</span></span></a></li>

Comment: webstrategyguy.com/Sites/ If apply the display:none attribute to the stylesheet, where in the stylesheet do I apply it?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get rid of that particular 'button,' the:

```
<span class="ui-btn-text">Close</span>
```

Then:

```
$('span.ui-btn-text').remove();
```

should work.

Comment: webstrategyguy.com/Sites/ If apply the display:none attribute to the stylesheet, where in the stylesheet do I apply it?